# write 2d array to CSV file swift

Tags: ios, swift, swift3

I am trying to write some data on `CSV file` and exporting the it
it is working but the problem is with the `2d array`, during writing it is considering `,` between the element of array as a separate column
Please see the picture which is showing the problem

[image]

But i need the result like below!

[image]

i have tried `String(describing:rythmReport.peakList[index])` but no gain

Comment: I think you need to use quotes `"` to escape commas in a csv, for ex: `"[634.0,655.0,...]"`

Comment: i am already doing this "\(String(describing:rythmReport.peakList[index]))" @NewDev

Comment: Show more of your code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CSV splits the column on every comma (,) occurrence.

You should enclose the column in quotes to have them as a single column.

This should work:
`"\"\(String(describing:rythmReport.peakList[index]))\""`

Other solution for this is using a TSV Tab (\t), Tab separated Values instead of using a comma as a delimiter

Comment: great really deserve thumbs up!